# value not saving in the Array c++

Tags: c++

I have been trying to make a tictactoe game but after i take the input the values inside the array are not changing. Everything looks fine can anyone help me with this. i have rewritten the code many times and also checked alot of times but no luck.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char gameArray[3][3] =
{ 
    '1', '2', '3', 
    '4', '5', '6', 
    '7', '8', '9' 
}; //making the board while also initializing it

char player = 'X'; //setting a default player
void switchPlayer() //Switches the player
{
    if (player == 'X')
    {
        player = 'O';
    }
    else
    {
        player = 'X';
    }
}
void input() //taking input for the game
{
    int userInput;
    cin >> userInput;
    if (userInput == 1)
    {
        gameArray[0][0] == player;
    }
    else if (userInput == 2)
    {
        gameArray[0][1] == player;
    }
}

void draw() //display the board
{
    cout << "\t  " << gameArray[0][0] << "|  " 
                   << gameArray[0][1] << "|  "
                   << gameArray[0][2] << endl;
    cout << "\t __|___|____\n";
    cout << "\t  " << gameArray[1][0] << "|  " 
                   << gameArray[1][1] << "|  "
                   << gameArray[1][2] << endl;
    cout << "\t __|___|____\n";
    cout << "\t  " << gameArray[2][0] << "|  " 
                   << gameArray[2][1] << "|  "
                   << gameArray[2][2] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Tic-Tac-Toe Game\n\n";
    draw();
    cout << "Player " << player << " turn. Enter the number to input: ";
    while (1)
    {
        input();
        draw();
        switchPlayer();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo: `gameArray[0][0] == player;` is comparison. You want assignment: `gameArray[0][0] = player;` Compiler may have been warning you about this with a *statement has no effect* message or similar. Never ignore compiler warnings. They are your first line of defense against little mistakes like this. In fact you want to turn them on and turn them up **LOUD!**

Comment: damn i totally unsaw that one thank you for the help

Comment: ffr, `gameArray[(userInput-1)/3][(userInput-1)%3] = player;` assuming `userInput` is in [1..9]. Save you from typing out the remaining seven conditions.

Comment: Thank you whoz. totally appreciated your help

Comment: @WhozCraig can you tell me from where i could learn algorithms like the one you wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are not assigning the value**

You have to change this line of code

```
    gameArray[0][0] == player;
    gameArray[0][1] == player;
```

By Replacing with this line

```
    gameArray[0][0] = player;
    gameArray[0][1] = player;
```